# Display Text instead value selected dropdown list by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown

i want when selected option color from dropdown list then displaye selected  text in `id="name_text"`

i could not  change Html form  code  I want only when selected option then display text selected

my code is not work :(

```
<select id="property-transection" name="property-transection">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="53"> Blue </option>
<option value="24"> Green  </option>
<option value="31"> Black  </option>
</select>   
<div id="name_txt">You selected (BLUE Or Green Or Black)</div>
   <script>
   $(document).on('change', '#property-transection', function() {
         $('#name_txt').text($(this).val());
        var po = this.val();

        if( po = '53'){
            var vb="BLUE COLOR SELECTED";
                $('#noate_o').text(vb);
        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
<select id="property-transaction" name="property-transaction">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="53">Blue</option>
  <option value="24">Green</option>
  <option value="31">Black</option>
</select>

<div id="name_txt">Color Name Populates Here</div>

<script>
  $(document).on('change', '#property-transaction', function() {
    $('#name_txt').text($('#property-transaction option:selected').text());
  });
</script>
```

Here's a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/w73bzgos/2/